# I want to navigate to sub-directory where require file exist ? using CSH script

Tags: csh

```
if(-f runme ) then
    cd `dirname $(find . -iname 'runme')`
    chmod +x runme
    source runme
    cd -
```

IS THIS TRUE IN CSH SCRIPT?

First it will search for runme file recursively throughout sub-directories , and if it is present then will go to that sub-directory where this file exist?

This is the question - is my logic right syntactically? I think the present code will search runme file in present directory.

I have a found a solution, so thought to share it below. I have also mentioned in a comment section also.

```
find . -name "runme" > find_runme.txt

# Just below line used to remove the file name i.e runme here from "find path", and returns only directory path.

set a = `cat find_runme.txt | sed 's/\(.*\/\).*/\1/g'` 
if (-z find_runme.txt) then
cd .
else
cd $a
endif

if(-f runme ) then
  #  cd `dirname $(find . -iname 'runme')`
    chmod +x runme
    setenv PATH /dv/project/agile/xcelium/test/install/install/tools.lnx86/bin:$PATH
    source runme
    cd -
```

Comment: First ask yourself whether the logic is correct logically. If you know that the `runme` script is available in the current directory, then why go search for it with `find`?

Comment: if runme file is present in the current directory then why should i ask this question.  Be logical before  saying irrelevant things.

Comment: Aakash, the first poster is trying to help you. You have asked if the script is correct logically. They suggested you work it through, so you're helping yourself instead of being dependent on others. Specifically, the first line translates as "If there's a file called runme in the current directory then..."

Comment: ...and the remainder says "Find where the runme file is, make it executable and source it. Finally, revert back to the previous working directory". But this is mostly unnecessary if the file really is in the current directory. Hence the first poster's question to you. It was a perfectly logical question and not at all irrelevant.

Comment: Hi @roaima , please read the question once again.

Comment: find . -name "runme" > find_runme.txt
# Just below line used to remove the file name i.e runme here from "find path", and returns only directory path.
set a = `cat find_runme.txt | sed 's/\(.*\/\).*/\1/g'` 
if (-z find_runme.txt) then
cd .
else
cd $a
endif

if(-f runme ) then
  #  cd `dirname $(find . -iname 'runme')`
    chmod +x runme
    setenv PATH /dv/project/agile/xcelium/test/install/install/tools.lnx86/bin:$PATH
    source runme
    cd -

Comment: The above comment is the solution .

Answer (score 1):

There's no good reason to be using `csh` in this century.

Here, though, I'd do:

```
find . -name runme -type f -execdir chmod +x '{}' ';' -execdir '{}' ';'
```

Which would work in any shell even `csh` assuming your `find` supports the `-execdir` BSD extension (very common these days).

That *executes* the `runme` files, it doesn't `source` them in the current shell instance though. In any case, `source`ing doesn't require execute permission.

In any case, no, your code is not valid csh syntax. But the good news if you don't know csh syntax yet, is that you don't need to learn it, because it's been known for at least 3 decades that scripting in csh is harmful and should not be done, so nobody should be expecting you to do so.

If you really found yourself needing to `source` a `runme` csh file from within a csh script whilst the current working directory is temporarily the parent of that file, the code would look more like:

```
foreach file ("`find . -name runme -type f`")
  cd $file:h:q || continue
  source $file:t:q
  cd - || break
end
```

Though note that it won't work if there are `runme` files whose path contain newline characters.